# Runit in Docker container does not pass on environment variables

Tags: docker, environment-variables, runit

I'm trying to run a multi-process app in Docker with runit serving as init process but runit does not pass environment variables to the app:

In Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["runit"]
```

The service file `/etc/service/app/run` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>&1

echo "ENV_VAR=$ENV_VAR"
exec app
```

When I run the docker container with `ENV_VAR` set, the variable doesn't get passed to the app by runit. Output:

```
# docker run --name container -e ENV_VAR=loremipsum -d IMAGE_NAME
# docker logs container
- runit: $Id: 25da3b86f7bed4038b8a039d2f8e8c9bbcf0822b $: booting.
- runit: warning: unable to open /dev/console: file does not exist
- runit: enter stage: /etc/runit/1
/etc/runit/1: 6: /etc/runit/1: /etc/init.d/rcS: not found
/etc/runit/1: 7: /etc/runit/1: /etc/init.d/rmnologin: not found
/etc/runit/1: 12: /etc/runit/1: /etc/init.d/rc: not found
- runit: warning: child failed: /etc/runit/1
- runit: leave stage: /etc/runit/1
- runit: enter stage: /etc/runit/2
ENV_VAR=
...
* app failed because ENV_VAR was not set correctly *
```

How can I make runit pass the environment variable to the service/app?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
ENV MY_ENV_VAR $MY_ENV_VAR
```

or

example here

```
ARG var_name
ENV env_var_name=$var_name
```

and

```
docker build --build-arg var_name=${VARIABLE_NAME} (...)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this can be used only for some static variables used during build. I need to have support for runtime environment variables so the user can set up some details when he runs the finished image.

Comment: i want know did you builded image with env ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What you suggested only allows the builder of the image to set the environment variable. It does not allow the user of the image to set anything. So it doesn't help me in this situation.

Answer (score -1):

I came by your question while working on similar setup and found out it was working for me so as you can see in my example below that you have the ability to call the environment variable directly.

Here is the example I have tested:

**Script 1**

```
# This is the run script that will be used for this dummy service
$ cat stackoverflow-question/run 
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>&1

exec echo "$Q_NUM"
```

**Script 2**

```
# This is the run script that will be used for this dummy service
$ cat stackoverflow-question/run 
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>&1

NUMBER=$Q_NUM

exec echo "$NUMBER"
```

I have used an image called [dockage/alpine-runit](https://hub.docker.com/r/dockage/alpine-runit/) for testing so feel free to use your own `runit` installation still applies.

Note: I Have tested both the default `CMD` that comes with this image and the `runit` command to reproduce your example and both worked as expected as you can see it prints the question number as we wanted.

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD:/service/" \
  -e Q_NUM=54089994 dockage/alpine-runit:latest runit
- runit: $Id: 25da3b86f7bed4038b8a039d2f8e8c9bbcf0822b $: booting.
- runit: enter stage: /etc/runit/1
- runit: leave stage: /etc/runit/1
- runit: enter stage: /etc/runit/2
54089994
54089994
54089994
54089994
```